# ssis 2005 query parameter date time cast fail

Tags: ssis

In my SSIS 2005 package, in OLE DB source (SQL Server 2005), I tried to execute a query with one parameter

The query in the OLE DB source

```
    select
    ...
    from..
    where
    txn_date_time >= ?
```

As you can see, the query takes one parameter from variable. The variable is type string and value is 20140622

Got this error in the OLE DB source when run the package.
...
Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

Also tried this and got the same error.
txn_date_time >=   cast(? as datetime)

The query can be run perfectly in SSMS, e.g.

```
    select
    ...
    from..
    where
    txn_date_time >= '20140622'
```

It seems to me that SSIS only allow parameter of type date time to be passed to the query because txn_date_time is type date time. Do I have to change the variable to type Date time?

Comment: you have already answered, Yes, please change and try it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of the value returned by your query and the data type of the parameter that you are mapping it to. They should be compatible else you get such cast exceptions.